# How to merge two tables

Tags: mysql

Given this relation of two tables

table1: (name, height, age)

table2: (cname, weight)

I want to combine name and cname so they are one with no duplicates. Like for example, let's say the name column for table1 had

```
name
bob
mary
alice
steve
```

while the cname column for table2 had

```
cname
bob
liam
abi
mark
```

I want to make a new name table like this:

```
name
bob
mary
alice
steve
liam
abi
mark
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM table1
    JOIN table2
        ON (table1.name = table2.cname)
```

I'm looking for a better join that'll make this work? Anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

```
SELECT name from Table1
UNION
SELECT cname from Table2
```

This will combine the distinct result from two select queries.

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/835c4c/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use both **`UNION`** and **`UNION ALL`** as per your requirement.

**UNION** removes duplicate records (where all columns in the results are the same), **`UNION ALL`** does not.

**Like:**

```
#if you need distinct records.

SELECT name from Table1
UNION
SELECT cname from Table2;

#if you need all records.

SELECT name from Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT cname from Table2;
```